# If K is normal in H, Can we say Core(H) is a subgroup of K?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

I found the following statement in a thesis and assume it is false and the converse is true. Am I correct or no? 
Let G be a finite group and H is a subgroup of G. Then if K is normal Subgroup of H, Can we say Core(H) is a subgroup of K?

Core(H) is the largest normal subgroup of G contained in H.

Thanks

Comment: no, if $H$ is normal in $G$, then $\operatorname{core} (H ) = H$ and if also $K \subsetneq H$ then this can't be true. Not under further assumptions.

Comment: No. If $H$ is normal in $G$, then $\mathrm{core}(H)=H$ need not be contained in $K$. For instance, take a group with a nontrivial center $H$, and take $K$ a proper subgroup of $H$.

Comment: So as I suggested the converse is true and Core(H) is not necessarily a subgroup of K unless K is the largest normal subgroup of G contained in H?

Comment: What converse? No, it is also not necessarily true that $K$ is contained in the core of $H$. Take $G=A_5$, $H$ the stabilizer of $5$ (hence isomorphic to $A_4$), and $K$ the Klein $4$-group that is normal in $H$. The core of $H$ is trivial in that case, and hence $K$ is not contained in the core.

Comment: @Mr.J If “$K$ is the largest normal subgroup of $G$ contained in $H$” then $K$ **is** the core, and your question would become whether the core is contained in the core/contains the core... which is a bit trivial.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin I meant, in case, K is the largest then the statement is true.

Comment: @Mr.J And as I note, if $K$ is the largest, then the statement is silly: in that case, the statement is “If $K$ is the core of $H$, is it true that $K$ contains the core of $H$?” In other words, the question would become “does $K$ contain itself?”.

Comment: Thank you very much that clarifies everything.